# Error propagation in dividing the averages of two data sets

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, error-propagation

Let's say I have two data sets each containing 1000 points. I want to get the respective averages of both data sets, then divide the resulting averages. What is the best way to propagate the error (e.g. SD) for this calculation?

Answer (score 1):

No, (Ave1 ± SD1)/(Ave2 ± SD2) is not how you would present the error in (Ave1/Ave2). If you have two variables, say $a$ and $b$, and you know the error in each of them, $\Delta{a}$ and $\Delta{b}$, respectively, then error in $c= \frac{a}{b}$ can be given as $\Delta{c} = \frac{a}{b}\cdot\sqrt{\left(\frac{\Delta{a}}{a} \right)^2+\left(\frac{\Delta{b}}{b} \right)^2}$. Your final result would be $c \pm \Delta{c}$.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes, that method was discussed in the link.

Comment: i editted the question for (hopefully) better clarity of what i wanted to calculate.