# Carrying over the standard deviation across calculations

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation

I have conducted a measurement of sample on an instrument. I thus have the value of my samples, of a blank, and the standard deviation of said blank. I would like to execute operations on the value of my sample and need help understanding how standard deviation carries over across these operations. Here,± designates SD. Sample-1 and sample-2 are replicates.

Starting data:

```
Blank = 136 ± 1.37
Sample-1 = 374
Sample-2 = 394
```

I then take into account the blank and standard deviation by doing `Adjusted sample = Blank - Sample`. I get:

```
Sample-1 = 238 ± 1.37
Sample-2 = 258 ± 1.37
```

I then do a linear operation (e.g. multiply by `k`) to convert to different units on both the value and standard deviation (to account for sample volume, which is equal in this case).

```
Sample-1 = 24 ± 0.09
Sample-2 = 26 ± 0.09
```

Now I'd like to get to the true measurement of my sample, so I average the two replicates. In terms of SD, I do `SD(Sample) = SD(Sample-1, Sample,2) + AVERAGE(SD(Sample-1) + SD(Sample-2)`. I get:

```
Sample = AV(24, 26) ± SD(24, 26) + AV(0.09, 0.09) 
Sample = 25 ± 1.5
```

I then convert the sample to a different unit again by a linear operation applied to the value and SD but lets disregard that here.

Now, I have a different measurement with its own standard deviation let's call it `Count = 2.86 ± 6.76`.

I would like to divide `Sample/Count`, here is where I think I make a mistake as I simply do `SD(SAMPLE)/SD(Count)`. Is that correct?

`Sample` and `Count` are not technically independent but I think can be considered as such here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To take the average of two variables: [Variance of an average of random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168971/variance-of-an-average-of-random-variables)
- Linear operations have no effect.
- See [Error propagation in dividing the averages of two data sets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363737/error-propagation-in-dividing-the-averages-of-two-data-sets)